# opendaylight: inconsistent api response

Tags: opendaylight

I have Opendaylight up and running but when I try to configure that through the REST api,

doing  exactly the same request, the 1st time I get an exception, and the 2nd time I get error message that the configuration is present already.

See below an example making the same request 2 times. 
One is causing an exception, another one returns a response

And I would like to ask you:

1. Where can I address this issue ?
2. I am trying to find some diagnostic
   restful GET commands for Opendaylight BGP configuration, for
   example; show me all BGP attributes for BGP session/group/neighbor.
   Where can I find that ?

   ```
   In [9]: cmd = """  <neighbor xmlns="urn:opendaylight:params:xml:ns:yang:bgp:openconfig-extensions">
      ...:     <neighbor-address>10.20.14.1</neighbor-address>
      ...:     <afi-safis>
      ...:         <afi-safi>
      ...:             <afi-safi-name>LINKSTATE</afi-safi-name>
      ...:         </afi-safi>
      ...:     </afi-safis>
      ...: </neighbor>
      ...: """

   In [10]: url = "/restconf/config/openconfig-network-instance:network-instances/network-instance/global-bgp/openconfig-network-instance:protocols/protocol/openconfig-policy-types:BGP/bgp-example/bgp/ne
       ...: ighbors"

   In [11]: 

   In [11]: requests.post('http://{}:{}{}'.format(odl['api']['ipaddr'],odl['api']['port'],url), auth=auth, headers=headers, data=cmd).json()
   ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
   JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
   <ipython-input-11-6c5beab7d9fb> in <module>()
   ----> 1 requests.post('http://{}:{}{}'.format(odl['api']['ipaddr'],odl['api']['port'],url), auth=auth, headers=headers, data=cmd).json()

   /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/models.py in json(self, **kwargs)
       894                     # used.
       895                     pass
   --> 896         return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
       897 
       898     @property

   /usr/lib64/python3.6/json/__init__.py in loads(s, encoding, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
       352             parse_int is None and parse_float is None and
       353             parse_constant is None and object_pairs_hook is None and not kw):
   --> 354         return _default_decoder.decode(s)
       355     if cls is None:
       356         cls = JSONDecoder

   /usr/lib64/python3.6/json/decoder.py in decode(self, s, _w)
       337 
       338         """
   --> 339         obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
       340         end = _w(s, end).end()
       341         if end != len(s):

   /usr/lib64/python3.6/json/decoder.py in raw_decode(self, s, idx)
       355             obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
       356         except StopIteration as err:
   --> 357             raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
       358         return obj, end

   JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

   In [12]: requests.post('http://{}:{}{}'.format(odl['api']['ipaddr'],odl['api']['port'],url), auth=auth, headers=headers, data=cmd).json()
   Out[12]: 
   {'errors': {'error': [{'error-type': 'protocol',
       'error-tag': 'data-exists',
       'error-message': 'Data already exists for path: /(http://openconfig.net/yang/network-instance?revision=2015-10-18)network-instances/network-instance/network-instance[{(http://openconfig.net/yang/network-instance?revision=2015-10-18)name=global-bgp}]/protocols/protocol/protocol[{(http://openconfig.net/yang/network-instance?revision=2015-10-18)identifier=(http://openconfig.net/yang/policy-types?revision=2015-10-09)BGP, (http://openconfig.net/yang/network-instance?revision=2015-10-18)name=bgp-example}]/AugmentationIdentifier{childNames=[(urn:opendaylight:params:xml:ns:yang:bgp:openconfig-extensions?revision=2017-12-07)bgp]}/(urn:opendaylight:params:xml:ns:yang:bgp:openconfig-extensions?revision=2017-12-07)bgp/neighbors/neighbor/neighbor[{(urn:opendaylight:params:xml:ns:yang:bgp:openconfig-extensions?revision=2017-12-07)neighbor-address=10.20.14.1}]'}]}}
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using POST which means create-if-not-exist so the second request is correctly returning a "data-exists" error as specified in the RESTCONF RFC.

Comment: why the 1st one causes an exception ?

Comment: The JSONDecodeError in the first call looks like it's coming from your Python code.

Comment: @iamsterdam if this answer works for you, can you mark as answered?